# How to implement doughnut ChartJS with CodeIgniter 3 and display data from database

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, chart.js

I've been trying to get doughnut chart to work with my CI3 application to no avail as this is my first time trying ChartJS out.

**What I tried**

**-PHP**

```
public function get( $data ) {
    if ( $this->input->is_ajax_request() ) {
        $this->load->library('user_utils');

        if ( $data == 'subscriptions' ) {
            $this->load->model('Fetcher', 'fetcher');

            $options = [
               // Database specific key/value pairs
            ];

            $fetch = $this->fetcher->fetch( 'where', $options );

            if ( $fetch ) {
                echo json_encode( $fetch->result_array() ); 

                // needs review
                $fetch->free_result();
            } else {
                print json_encode( 'false' );
            } 
        }
    } else {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

**-JS**

```
$(function() {
if ($("#subChart").length) {
    // donut chart data
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'dashboard/get/subscriptions',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            var subscriptions = {
                status : []
            };
            var len = response.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                subscriptions.status.push(response[i].subscriptions);
            }
            var chart = $("#subChart");
            var fontFamily = '"Proxima Nova W01", -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif';

            // set defaults
            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = fontFamily;
            Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.titleFontSize = 14;
            Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.titleMarginBottom = 4;
            Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.displayColors = false;
            Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodyFontSize = 12;
            Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.xPadding = 10;
            Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.yPadding = 8;
            var data = {
                labels: ["Processed", "Pending", "Cancelled"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: subscriptions.status,
                        backgroundColor: ["#85c751", "#6896f9", "#d97b70"],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: ["#85c751", "#6896f9", "#d97b70"],
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                ]
            };

            // -----------------
            // init donut chart
            // -----------------
            new Chart(chart, {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: data,
                options: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    animation: {
                        animateScale: true
                    },
                    cutoutPercentage: 80
                }
            });
        }
    })
}
});
```

I'm getting the chart data through ajax on page load, what i'm i missing?, should I set default chart data and update them after fetching thorugh ajax first?
Your answer will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The answer to your last question is yes, you should set some default chart data, probably to 0 or 360 degrees, or however chartjs does donuts. When you get the response back, is it what you are expecting?

Comment: console log is your friend

Comment: @Alex that has not been helpful :-(

Comment: @BrianGottier sorry for the late response. Forgive me for not going through the ChartJS documentation properly, i was in a hurry to get it working. Didn't know there's an update method. But i was expecting some sort of data update to MAGICALLY happen too. Will try setting default values and calling the `update()` method.

Comment: @BrianGottier did what you suggested after going through the documentation and it worked impressively fine, thanks man. Will post the working solution as an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the [ChartJS documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html), I found and utilized the `.update(config)` method after previously initializing my chart with dummy data. Here's what the JavaScript file looks like now:

```
$(function() {
if ($("#subChart").length) {
    var chart = $("#subChart");
    var fontFamily = '"Proxima Nova W01", -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif';
    
    // set defaults
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = fontFamily;
    Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.titleFontSize = 14;
    Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.titleMarginBottom = 4;
    Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.displayColors = false;
    Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodyFontSize = 12;
    Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.xPadding = 10;
    Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.yPadding = 8;
    var data = {
        labels: ["Processed", "Pending", "Cancelled"],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [1, 1, 1],
                backgroundColor: ["#85c751", "#6896f9", "#d97b70"],
                hoverBackgroundColor: ["#85c751", "#6896f9", "#d97b70"],
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        ]
    };

    // -----------------
    // init donut chart
    // -----------------
    var subsChart = new Chart(chart, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: data,
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true
            },
            cutoutPercentage: 80
        }
    });

    // donut chart data
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'dashboard/get/subscriptions',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(obj);
            console.log(obj[0].count);

            var active = obj[0].count;
            var pending = obj[1].count;
            var cancelled = obj[2].count;

            console.log('Initial value:' + subsChart.data.datasets[0].data);
            subsChart.data.datasets[0].data[0] = active;
            subsChart.data.datasets[0].data[1] = pending;
            subsChart.data.datasets[0].data[2] = cancelled;
            subsChart.update(); 

            console.log('Updated value:' + subsChart.data.datasets[0].data);
        }
    })
 }
});
```

and here's the output:
[image: Browser Output]

Many thanks to @briangottier